# How to get active listing with forward slash (/) in SKU using Flipkart Seller GET LISTING API?

Tags: rest, api, flipkart-api

I am trying to use flipkart seller api to get connected with flipkart seller account.

When I passed SKU with forward slash ('/') in Get Listing API, I got an error which is as shown below -

{"errors":[{"severity":"ERROR","code":10000,"description":"HTTP 404 Not Found"}]}

I have also tried with URL encoding for forward slash (%2F) but I was getting the error "Invalid SKU".

This is the URL from where I am trying to get product -

CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/listings/v3/18AW161336-824/35/32"

Please help me with a solution to get the products having forward slashes (/) in their SKU id's?

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the forward slash (`/`) with a backslash (`\`).